# cannot directly call the php file inside folders using the directory path

Tags: php, css, url, directory

I have one root folder called GASS where I put all my php files and other related folders (templates,images,js,fonts,css)inside. When i try to run my project in localhost, `http://localhost/GASS/alarm_A16GSM.php` everything went smoothly. I wanted to change the URL to be more specific, `http://localhost/GASS/alarmsystem/16zone/A16/overview.php` thus i rename the php file and put it inside folders.

- GASS

  - alarm-system

    - 16-zone

      - A16

        - overview

However when i try to run the new URL,the page shows error.This is the error message:

```
Warning: include(templates/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .....
```

Code for the first URL where the page load successfully.

```
 <div class="overview"><a href="alarm_A16GSM.php" id="overview-selected"><span>
```

Code for the new URL where the page shows error.

```
<a href="alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php" id="overview-selected">
```

It seems like i need to configure something which i do not know what it is.

How am i going to load the page successfully using the new URL? How am i going to traverse four levels up to the root directory so that the page load successfully? Why i cannot directly call the php file using the(alarm-system/16-zone/A16/overview.php) path?

p/s: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: By the way, you should look into 'routing'. It's a way of making your URLs independent of your directory and file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a line in your Php file, probably like

```
include 'templates/header.php';
```

Include can't find the file using that relative path, because you moved the calling file.

Probably you could change that to

```
include '../../../../templates/header.php';
```

To get back down to the GASS folder that apparently has a folder called 'templates' with a file 'header.php' that is required.

An absolute path would be good, instead but it refers to the filesystem path, not webserver path - so you'd need to know your web root folder name on the server.

Comment: i got it!! thanks alot! its just that i reach the template 3 levels up only. so i think supposely the answer would be   include'../../../templates/header.php'

Comment: Cool, glad it worked! I also thought that a better solution might be to use a command to add the base directory to your PHP include path. I'll update with some code for that if that helps.

Comment: how can i call the css inside the root folder? The URL is working fine,but the page only shows words and description. Without any css styling. how can i fix this?

Comment: You need to do the same thing for the <link> tags that embed the external CSS files, i presume

Comment: i put this code link href="../../../css/gass_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> inside the overview.php file. The page load successfully. However the image is gone. why is this happening?

Comment: It sounds like the CSS references an image, which now is in a different directory like all this other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Copying all the folders (templates,images,js,fonts,css) to the folder overview will solve the issue. Now there is no template file on the folder 'overview' so header.php is failed to load. Another option is create a file save all the included file path and call this file.

Comment: thanks. it works:-) is there any other solution that I can use ? Other than copying all the folders